# How to get the value of selected item in a xlDropDown which is added programmatically to a Excel sheet cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, office-interop

The following code shows the way i created the drop downs programmatically. It works fine. But now I need to get value of a specific dropdown of a cell.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDowns xlDropDowns;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDown xlDropDown;
xlDropDowns = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDowns)(sheet.DropDowns(Type.Missing)));
xlDropDown = xlDropDowns.Add((double)rag.Left, (double)rag.Top, (double)rag.Width, double)rag.Height, true);
var DropDownList = {"aaaa","bbbb","cccc","dddd"};

int x = 0;
foreach (var item in DropDownList)
{
    x++;
    xlDropDown.AddItem(item);
}
```

This is how i tried to get the xlDropDown value. currentCell is the cell where i have the drop down

```
ColumnVal = currentCell.Text; // This didnt give any output
```

OR

```
var dd = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDown)currentCell.DropDowns(Type.Missing);
```

I know the 2nd one is wrong, because the cell range and drop down are 2 different things. But I tried all the options, still couldnt find any solution. Someone please help me

More clearly, I want to access a specific cell(currentCell), and the xldropdown it contains and then get value from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you would need a reference to the drop down you've just added:

*Assuming there's only one drop down, the below would do

```
xlDropDown = ((Excel.DropDown)(xlDropDowns.Item(1)));
```

then you need to access the `.get_List()` property of the `Excel.DropDown` while making sure that something has been selected.

Example:

```
if (xlDropDown.Value > 0)
{
    sht.get_Range("A1").Value = xlDropDown.get_List(xlDropDown.Value);
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("Nothing was selected yet");
}
```

---

Identifying the dropdowns:

You could a for each loop on the `xlDropDowns` collection and grab the `.Name` and `.ListIndex` of each `xlDropDown`?

```
foreach (Excel.DropDown xlDD in xlDropDowns)
{
    MessageBox.Show(xlDD.Name + ", " + xlDD.ListIndex);
}
```

Comment: In my case I have multiple drop downs and I have to access them through cell range which I already know. Can you suggest a way to do that.

Comment: I am confused. You are adding a MSForms dropdown to a spreadsheet and the way to access its value it's how I showed you in the answer. If you have different type of dropdown how is the code you've provided relevant to the question?

Comment: What you said is right. But you have made an assumption that there is only one drop down. And you used item(1).
But in my case i have many, and i dont think I could use item(number). Because I dont know the number or the order of each and every drop down .
What Im asking is, is there a way to find out the ID or item no of my dropdowns individually

Comment: This method would do if I just need to get all the dropdowns and its name. But what I have is, a excel table with 3 columns having dropdowns in each cell. I know the cell range value.

    ex:- Excel.Range range = (Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[row,col];
And I need to access cell by cell and get its name.

Comment: That's a totally different question, isn't it? I believe that your original question should now be solved. Please consider marking it as solved and ask a new question if you have a new one. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I dont think this a different question. Because in the beginning I have said that I used the cell 'currentCell' to try to get value from the drop down in that specific cell. So if u can please help me. I want to access a specific cell(currentCell), and the xldropdown it contains and then get value from it

Comment: I still don't understand where you are struggling. The type of the dropdown you have added using your current code can't be accessed directly via a cell's reference ie. the cell isn't associated with the dropdown...

Comment: This is what i was struggling on. Your last comment was my doubt all the time. Both cant be associated. 
Atlast thanks a lot. Now I have to get all the drop down names as u said and find a way to access it. Thank u again :)